# Python: Using ExcelWriter - How to Label Multiple Pandas DataFrames With Titles

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, writer

I have a script that inserts multiple Pandas DataFrames into a single Excel Worksheet. Unfortunately, I am unable to distinguish between these tables without the tables containing titles. How can I go about accomplishing this?

```
def multiple_dfs(df_list, sheets, file_name, spaces):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='xlsxwriter', datetime_format = 'mmmm yyyy')
    row = 0
    for dataframe in df_list:
        dataframe.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheets,startrow=row , startcol=0)
        row = row + len(dataframe.index) + spaces + 2
    writer.save()

# list of dataframes
dfs = [Summary_Loans_by_month, Summary_Loans_by_year, Summary_df_Coll_by_month, Summary_df_Coll_by_year,
       Summary_df_Pers_by_month, Summary_df_Pers_by_year, Summary_df_Other_by_month, Summary_df_Other_by_year,
       Summary_df_Refi_by_month, Summary_df_Refi_by_year, Summary_Scores_m, Summary_Scores_y, Summary_Scores_m_col,
       Summary_Scores_y_col, Summary_Scores_m_per, Summary_Scores_y_per, Summary_Scores_m_refi, Summary_Scores_y_refi,
       Summary_Scores_m_other, Summary_Scores_y_other]

# run function
multiple_dfs(dfs, 'KPI-2017', 'KPI-2017.xlsx', 1)
```

Comment: would adding a column to the dataframes distinguishing their identity be a viable solution?

Comment: I guess I could do that. I'd prefer to just have a title in a blank cell between dataframes

Comment: you could always create a blank dataframe and just have the column names be the indicators? that way it "looks" like a blank space. However, for any reporting purposes such as SQL, Tableau, Pivot Tables, etc. any space of non-data field would really be a damper for the end users.

Comment: @MattR. Okay I will try that - thanks

Comment: Why not put dataframes in different worksheets of same workbook?

Comment: That's how it was arranged before. However, there could be up to 15 tabs which makes it a little unintuitive to read through.